# Table migration to a different remote

Tags: postgresql

I have this one table A with table header q_, w_, e_ on remote database 1. I would like to move this table A to a table B with table header q, w, e on remote database 2. In my case, remote database 1 is my database instance on Digital Ocean whereas remote database 2 is a managed database instance.

How can I achieve this on Postgres?